# Forgot My Username and Password for Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, command, solver, recovery

I am using SQL Developer for Oracle, but I forgot my username and password. I need help finding the username and password
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOFxX.png)

Is there a command-line option for recovering my username and password from the login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should be able to connect to database, somehow. If there's a DBA available to you, contact them and ask for assistance. If you're a DBA, then you'll have to do it yourself.

If operating system user you're connected to also *owns* Oracle database software, try with operating system authentication:

```
c:\temp>sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Oracle *trusts* that this (operating system) user is allowed to establish connection.

My operating system user isn't *the one*, but I do know `sys` password so I can connect:

```
c:\temp>sqlplus sys@pdb1 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Jan 21 16:48:28 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
```

OK, we're in.

You said you don't know your username; that's kind of unusual as people forget passwords, but do know usernames. Never mind that objection; query `all_users` and see whether any of these ring a bell. If not, then I presume nobody can help you. I recognize *my* user, its name is `SCOTT`:

```
SQL> select username from all_users where username like 'S%';

USERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS
SYSTEM
SYSBACKUP
SYSDG
SYSKM
SYSRAC
SYS$UMF
SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA
SCOTT                             --> this one

9 rows selected.
```

If you don't know its password, reset it:

```
SQL> alter user scott identified by tiger;

User altered.
```

Connect as `SCOTT`, using newly set password:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@pdb1
Connected.
SQL>
```

That's all.